# java to kotlin language translation problem with mutuable lists

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist

I translated the following java snippet to kotlin:

JAVA:

```
    List<Double> xSecRaw = new ArrayList();
    // Create a HashSet which allows no duplicates
    hashSet = new HashSet(xSecRaw);

    // Assign the HashSet to a new ArrayList
    xSec = new ArrayList(hashSet);

    // Ensure correct order, since HashSet doesn't
    Collections.sort(xSec);
```

Kotlin:

```
    val xSecRaw: MutableList<Double?> = ArrayList<Double?>()

    // Create a HashSet which allows no duplicates
    hashSet = HashSet<Any?>(xSecRaw)

    // Assign the HashSet to a new ArrayList
    xSec = ArrayList<Any?>(hashSet) // <--- this line gives error!

    // Ensure correct order, since HashSet doesn't
    Collections.sort(xSec)
```

the error is:

Type mismatch.

Required: MutuableList

Found: ArrayList

any hint?

I want to eliminate the duplicates in the xSecRaw and sort them

Comment: `xSec = hashSet.toArrayList()`

Comment: Hi, it's probably a better idea to copy/paste the error messages as people google them all the time. If you rewrite the error messages, they're prone to typos and people won't find them as easily

Comment: Yes I was not able to copy and paste from Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you use raw types in your Java code (you use `HashSet(....)` instead of `HashSet<SomeType>(....)`), and raw types are translated into types that use `Any?` as their generic type, and MutableList< Any?> can't be assigned to MutableList< Double?> (as you are trying to do in the failing line). If you change your Java code like this:

```java
List<Double> xSecRaw = new ArrayList<>();
// Create a HashSet which allows no duplicates
hashSet = new HashSet<Double>(xSecRaw);

// Assign the HashSet to a new ArrayList
xSec = new ArrayList<Double>(hashSet);

// Ensure correct order, since HashSet doesn't
Collections.sort(xSec);
```

Then it will probably translated into this:

```
val xSecRaw: MutableList<Double?> = ArrayList<Double?>()

// Create a HashSet which allows no duplicates
hashSet = HashSet<Double?>(xSecRaw)

// Assign the HashSet to a new ArrayList
xSec = ArrayList<Double?>(hashSet) // <--- this line gives error!

// Ensure correct order, since HashSet doesn't
Collections.sort(xSec)
```

And this code will work (you should change `Double?` to `Double` if you don't need nullable `Double`s in your collection)

Also, if you want to remove duplicates from list and sort it, you can just write

```
xSec = xSecRaw.distinct().sorted()
```

instead of all your code.

Comment: thnk You! I will stay with the oneliner!

Comment: the oneliner is not producing a list, I need that because later on I use "removeAt" on xSec

Comment: It produces `List`, not `MutableList`. You can make it mutable if you write `xSec = xSecRaw.distinct().sorted().toMutableList()`

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
val xSecRaw: MutableList<Double?> = mutableListOf<Double?>()
```